# Cannot calculate specific dimensions for composable TextField

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, textfield

I am trying to create multiple items to encapsulate the specific behavior of every component but I cannot specify the dimensions for every view.

I want a Textfield with an X icon on its right

```
        setContent {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = white)
                .padding(horizontal = 15.dp)
        ) {
                Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(15.dp)) {
                    Searcher(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                        onTextChanged = { },
                        onSearchAction = { }
                    )
                    Image(
                        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_close),
                        contentDescription = null,
                        colorFilter = ColorFilter.tint(blue)
                    )
                }

            }
        }
```

The component is the following

```
@Composable
fun Searcher(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onSearchAction: () -> Unit
) {
    Row {
        SearcherField(
            onTextChanged = onTextChanged,
            onSearchAction = onSearchAction,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        )

        CircularSearch(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(horizontal = 10.dp)
                .align(CenterVertically)
        )
    }
}
```

and the SearcherField:

```
@Composable
fun SearcherField(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onTextChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    onSearchAction: () -> Unit
) {

    var fieldText by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyText) }

    TextField(
        value = fieldText,
        onValueChange = { value ->
            fieldText = value
            if (value.length > 2)
                onTextChanged(value)
        },
        singleLine = true,
        textStyle = Typography.h5.copy(color = White),
        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
            cursorColor = White,
            focusedIndicatorColor = Transparent,
            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Transparent,
            backgroundColor = Transparent
        ),
        trailingIcon = {
            if (fieldText.isNotEmpty()) {
                IconButton(onClick = {
                    fieldText = emptyText
                }) {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Close,
                        contentDescription = emptyText
                    )
                }
            }
        },
        placeholder = {
            Text(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.dondebuscas),
                style = Typography.h5.copy(color = White)
            )
        },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Search),
        keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
            onSearch = {
                onSearchAction()
            }
        ),
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    )
}
```

But I don´t know why, but the component Searcher with the placeholder is rendered in two lines.

It´s all about the placeholder that seems to be resized for not having enough space because if I remove the placeholder, the component looks perfect.

Everything is in one line, not having a placeholder of two lines. I m trying to modify the size of every item but I am not able to get the expected result and I don´t know if the problem is just about the placeholder.

How can I solve it? **UPDATE** -> I found the error

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... I find that the problem is about the trailing icon. Is not visible when there is no text in the TextField but is still occupying some space in the view, that´s why the placeholder cannot occupy the entire space. The solution is the following.

```
    val trailingIconView = @Composable {
        IconButton(onClick = {
            fieldText = emptyText
        }) {
            Icon(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Close,
                contentDescription = emptyText
            )
        }
    }
```

Create a variable with the icon and set it to the TextField only when is required

```
trailingIcon = if (fieldText.isNotEmpty()) trailingIconView else null,
```

With that, the trailing icon will be "**gone**" instead of "**invisible**" (the old way).

Still have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 0):

Add `maxlines = 1` to the placeholder `Text`'s parameters.

Your field is single -lune but your text is multi-line. I think it creates conflict in implementation.

Comment: With that solution avoids expanding the component vertically into two lines but the placeholder only shows the first part of the placeholder.

Comment: Sir.. the placeholder will either need two lines to display or be cut in half... What exactly do you want to achieve here? If you want the best of both worlds, reduce font size